# Z=X+Y pdf, there is a part I can't understand.

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Two independent random variable X,Y which is U(0,1)

what is the pdf of Z=X+Y?

$F_Z(z)$ =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \ z\le0 \\
\int_0^z \int_0^{z-y} 1 \,dxdy=z^2/2, & \ 0\lt z\le1 \\
1-\int_\bbox[yellow]{z-1}^1 \int_{z-y}^1 1 \,dxdy=1-(2-z)^2/2,& \ 1\lt z\le2 \\
1 & \ z\ge2
\end{cases}

I understand I have to differential $F_z(z)$

The thing I can't understand is the highlight part.

Why does it starts with z-1?

Comment: By union, did you mean uniform? The usual notation for this distribution is $U(0,\,1)$.

Comment: @J.G. Thank you I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Convolution of probability densities

Let $X$ and $Y$ be *any* two independent (real-valued) random variables with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$.
Define $Z \equiv X + Y$.
Note that
$$
F_Z(z)
= \mathbb{P}(Z \leq z)
= \mathbb{P}(X + Y \leq z)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) \mathbb{P}(x + Y \leq z) dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) F_Y(z - x) dx.
$$
Differentiating,
$$
f_Z(z)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x) f_Y(z - x) dx.
$$

---

## Convolution of i.i.d. uniform distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. $U(0,1)$, then $f_x = f_Y = \boldsymbol{1}_{(0,1)}$ where $\boldsymbol{1}$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).
Plugging this into the integral of the previous section,
$$
f_Z(z)
= \int_0^1 \boldsymbol{1}_{(0,1)}(z - x) dx.
$$
Proceeding by cases,
$$
f_Z(z)
= \begin{cases}
\int_0^z dx = z & \text{if } 0 \leq z \leq 1 \\
\int_\bbox[yellow]{z-1}^1 dx = 2 - z & \text{if } 1 \leq z \leq 2. \\
\end{cases}
$$